# RoR Tutorial Section 5.5 db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm new to Ruby. I'm at RoR Getting Started Section 5.5 and after running db:migrate, got the below error. Any advise on why? I can't find any answers or solution or problem. Pls help.

> $ bin/rake db:migrate
>
> == 20150207172154 CreateArticles: migrating ===================================
>   -- create_table(:articles)    -> 0.0017s
>   == 20150207172154 CreateArticles: migrated (0.0019s) ==========================
>
> rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later
>   migrations canceled:
>
> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)-e:1:in `<main>' ArgumentError:
>   wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
>   -e:1:in`' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Below is my migration file.

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration    def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end      
  end  
end
```

Comment: When posting a question on SO please post the information that is related to your question and necessary to answer.  In this instance we need to see your migration file.

Comment: oic. will do that in future. what's SO?

Comment: SO = Stack Overlow = This site you posted this questions on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error that I ran into once, and it's because of Arel gem, to solve it, go to Gemfile, and add this line

```
gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
```

then run `bundle` from the terminal. If it complains about Arel, then install it from the terminal by typing `bundle update arel`. Then migrate your database again.

Comment: Np, please accept and upvote my answer :) it helps me and other people

Comment: hmm.. i'm new here and seems like i don't have enough 15 reputation to do an upvote. i've "tick" the correct answer. how to up my reputation?

Comment: Ticking the correct answer is enough. but to increase your reputations you need to answer questions. Or ask good questions that people upvote.

Comment: can you please have a look at my question here: [arel_not_working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67240230/migration-of-rubyonrails-5-to-6-0-1-dbmigrate-creates-no-tables)